# Preprocessor dependency "sass" not found

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass

[I install saas using npm i saas and when i create file name using app.sccs then it show this error and i also install its dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jmtQ.png)

i just create project using vite(react+typescript) for creating my personal project and I install saas for making more good looking, **using npm i saas** and when i create file name using **app.sccs** then it show this error and i also install its dependency, Need help do we need to require or import saas in vite(react + typescript) or how can i overcome from this

Comment: Have you accidentally typed `saas` twice instead of `sass` in your post or have you perhaps installed the wrong thing?

Answer (score 0):

**Install dependencies.**
Make sure you have **Sass** and **Sass-Loader** installed.

`npm install -D sass sass-loader`

Vite configuration:
Update  **Vite** settings to handle **SASS** files. You need to add the **SASS** plugin to your `vite.config.js` or `vite.config.ts` file.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "./path/to/your/variables";`, // Optional: Import your global variables
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Replace `"./path/to/your/variables"` with the path to your SASS global variables file.

If you create a file named app.scss or another .scss file, be sure to import it or include it in your React component.
`import './app.scss';`